# How to create a nasted widget based on selecting a choice from a dropdown in jupyter lab/ipywidgets?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

How to generate a  widget based on selecting an option from a dropdown menu? I have an example code is given below?

```
from ipywidgets import *
x = Dropdown(options=['a', 'b'])
#y = Dropdown(options=['1', '2'])
 
x.observe(change_x, 'value')

HBox([x])
```

For example,  based on selecting 'a' It should create and display a second drop-down menu 'y'  and on selecting 'b' It should create and display a text box.

Thank you.